# Is not show change in template page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Sir i have one wordpress website on godaddy server and in this if i am going to changes in page template file then these changes are show to me on that page only after admin login otherwise its not changes shows to me on that pages template Sir please help me about this issue

Comment: First guess would be that you probably have some sort of _caching_ plugin in use.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using any cache plugin. If so, try clear the cache or disable the cache plugin and see whether the new updates are reflecting on the website.